# as3corelib serialization goes wrong

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I get error

> Error #2099: The loading object is not sufficiently loaded to provide this information

when I try to encode object into JSON using as3corelib.
I succeeded encoding some value object which has no parent or children so I know that library works and that problem might be related to addChild or something like that. That is just guess.

Board is added to stage like that:

```
stage.addChild(board);
```

When I don't add board to stage and try to serialize it I get different error:

```
undefined
at XML/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::copy()
at global/describeTraits()
at global/avmplus::describeType()
at global/flash.utils::describeType()
    ...
```

Board class:

```
public class Board extends Sprite
{
    public var board:Array;
    public var blockColor:uint = 0xE3E3E3;
    public var blockLength:uint

    public function Board(blockLength:uint)
    {
        super();
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        this.blockLength = blockLength;
        //buttonMode = true;
        // Setting up two dim array
        board = new Array(10);
        for (var k:int = 0; k < board.length; k++) 
        {
            board[k] = new Array(10);
        }


        for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
        { 
            for(var j:int = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            {
                var block:Block = new Block(i*blockLength, j*blockLength);  
                board[i][j] = block;
                this.addChild(block); // here I add children
                block.drawBlock(blockLength, blockColor);
                block.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, blockClicked);
            }
        }           
    }

    ....

}
```

}

Here is code for Block, really nothing there.

```
public class Block extends Sprite
{

    public var cos:int = 5; // test

    public function Block(x:uint, y:uint)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function drawBlock(length:uint, color:uint):void
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Any clues why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you don't try to serialize any form of `DisplayObject`; instead you should just be serializing the underlying Data (attributes) which the View uses; it's hard to give you an exact answer from the code above, but consider the following:

```
// Simple Model object which represents the BlockView's underlying data.
public class BlockViewModel {
    public var x : Number;
    public var y : Number;
}

// Renders the BlockViewModel on screen.
public class BlockView extends Sprite {
    public var position : BlockViewModel;

    // Constructor requires a BlockViewModel object.
    public function BlockView(position : BlockViewModel) {
        this.position = position;
        draw();
        reposition();
    }

    private function draw() : void {
        // Omitted...
    }

    // Update the block's position based on the model.
    private function reposition() : void {
        this.x = this.position.x;
        this.y = this.position.y;
    }

    // Setter for the block's current position.
    public function setX(value : Number) : void {
        this.position.x = value;
        reposition();
    }
}
```

With the example above you would just serialize the `BlockViewModel` object when you want to save state, eg:

```
var serailizedBlockData : String = JSON.encode(blockView.position);
```

You could then re-create a new BlockView by deserializing the data:

```
// Convert from JSON -> Object.
var blockData : Object = JSON.decode(serializedBlockData);

// Create and populate a BlockViewModel with the deserialized data.
var position : BlockViewModel = new BlockViewModel();
position.x = blockData.x;
position.y = blockData.y;

// Create a new view using the serialized data.
var blockView = new BlockView(position);
```

You could extend this further by moving the object construction / population logic into a [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to help separate the logic.